# Hierarchical combinations between multiple arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, combinations

Let's assume I have three arrays `a`, `b` and `c`.
I want to get all combinations of elements taken from `[a,b,c]`,`[b,c]` and `[c]` but not `[a,c]`.

My working recursive function is as follows, taking as parameter the array of arrays `[a,b,c]` :

```
function allPossibleCases(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return [];
  } else if (arr.length === 1) {
    return arr[0];
  } else {
    var result=[];  
    var allCasesOfRest = allPossibleCases(arr.slice(1));
    for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
      for (var c in allCasesOfRest) {
        if (allCasesOfRest[c].split("~").length === arr.length-1) {
          result.push(arr[0][i]+"~"+allCasesOfRest[c]);  
        }
        result.push(allCasesOfRest[c]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
};
```

And I then `map` the result using the `.split("~")` function on the resulting array of strings to get an array of arrays containing my combinations.

I can't figure out how to elegantly make the recursion hierarchical without testing the length of the splitted `allCasesOfRest[c]` before pushing it into `result` (the length of the array resulting of the split should be `arr.length-1`).

Any ideas ?